# terraform still looking for azure cli login when using Azure Service Principal

Tags: terraform, azure-rm

I'm fairly new to Terraform. I'm trying to use Azure Service Principal for terraform. My code looks like below. However when I run `terraform init`, I get an error `Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: parsing json result from the Azure CLI: waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account.`

(I have deliberately logged out of Azure CLI to verify that the terraform code is NOT using azure cli. And looks like it's still looking for Azure CLI.)

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "=3.0.0"
    }
  }
  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name  = "rg-XXXX"
    storage_account_name = "saXXXXX"
    container_name       = "XXXXX"
    key                  = "XXXXX"
  }
}


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  client_id       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  client_secret   = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  tenant_id       = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are missing info allowing terraform to connect to the azurerm backend.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/azurerm#resource_group_name-2

You need to add client_id, client_secret and tenant_id in the backend configuration

```
backend "azurerm" {
  resource_group_name  = "rg-XXXX"
  storage_account_name = "saXXXXX"
  container_name       = "XXXXX"
  key                  = "XXXXX"
  client_id            = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  client_secret        = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  tenant_id            = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

You may use environment variables for this. You won't have to repeat them and it will allow you to commit your template to a source code repository without sensitive information.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this @sylvainmtz! I didn't realize that the client details had to be repeated in the backend portion of the code since it's been mentioned in the provider section.

Following the instructions by explicitly mentioning the client details, I was able to run my terraform code without azure cli and the tfstate was stored successfully in the azure location.